# SQL-server 'WEEKDAY' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql-server, date, weekday

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v18.9.2 which I downloaded about a month ago (Aug. 2021).
I've searched for help here on SO, SQLServerTutorial.net, and w3schools.com, and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to get three columns in the results: `RentalID`, `StartTime` (which exists as a datetime data type), and a new column with the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, etc.). I've limited the query to just the records since June 2021.

I've tried these three function names: weekday, dw, and w, in upper and lower case combinations, and all return the same error:

```
SELECT RentalID, StartTime, DATENAME(WEEKDAY(StartTime)) AS DayOfWeek
FROM FullData
WHERE StartTime > '2021-05-31'
```

Error msg: `'WEEKDAY' is not a recognized built-in function name`.

Then I get an error with this:

```
DATENAME(WEEKDAY(StartTime)) AS DayOfWeek
FROM FullData
WHERE StartTime > '2021-05-31'
```

Error msg:   `Incorrect syntax near 'WEEKDAY'`.

Then I get an error with this:

```
DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartTime) AS DayOfWeek
FROM FullData
WHERE StartTime > '2021-05-31'
```

Error msg: `Incorrect syntax near 'WEEKDAY'`.

When I try out the `MONTH` function, I get a different error:

```
SELECT RentalID, StartTime, DATENAME(MONTH(StartTime)) AS Month
FROM FullData
WHERE StartTime > '2021-05-31'
ORDER BY Month
```

Error msg:   `The datename function requires 2 argument(s).` I thought the 2 arguments would be the `MONTH` and `StartTime` but I guess, not.

Comment: You try to use `WEEKDAY` like a function in the first, and then omit the `SELECT` in the latter statements. Both of these looks like typographical errors to me.

Comment: *"I'm using SQL Server Management Studio v18.9.2"* this has nothing to do with what version of SQL Server you're using. It's like telling someone you're using Office 2013 when asked what Windows Version you have installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the date part as a function call not as an argument to the `datename` function:

```sql
DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartTime) AS DayOfWeek
-- Two args ----^
```

Or

```sql
DATENAME(MONTH, StartTime) AS [Month]
-- Two args --^
```

Comment: Get Incorrect syntax near 'WEEKDAY' error with this code:  
DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartTime) AS DayOfWeek
FROM FullData
WHERE StartTime > '2021-05-31'

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for [`DATENAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) has two arguments:

```
DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartTime)

DATENAME(MONTH, StartTime)
```

Comment: Still get same error with this code:  
DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartTime) AS DayOfWeek
FROM FullData
WHERE StartTime > '2021-05-31'

Comment: @LisaNV . . . It works fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=780d2ffdf360a05d779ae401e7ba1abc

Comment: So, frustrated. I took the WHERE clause out and it worked.

Comment: @LisaNV You missed `SELECT` at the beginning